# Microsoft Word text underline layered over text different to preview

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, office-for-mac, underlining

I am having an issue with Microsoft Word where the underline of underlined text is showing layered on top of the text (specifically drop letters). I've coloured this underline, which is why I've seen the issue. When looking at the font preview, I can see it with the underline behind the text, but then in my main Word document, it's sitting in front. I've tried this on Mac and Windows and with different fonts.

I need this to be like the preview, showing the text as the top-layer item, rather than the underline.

Both Mac and Windows Word installations were the latest versions.

Font settings preview (how I want it to look):
[image: Font settings preview (how I want it to look)]

Document window:
[image: Document window]

Comment: It seems to be the default setting and no possible to change it. The underline line is also over the text in Word 2013 and Word 2010.

Comment: Interestingly enough this seems to be fixed in Office 2016